# Do I always need to defer stmt.close() when I use prepared statement in golang?

Tags: sql, database, go

According to the post here, http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html, there is no defer stmt.close(). However, there is a stmt.close() API in sql package. I can't seem to find information on whether it is necessary to defer closing the stmt when using prepared statement. Hence, the question - Do I always need to defer stmt.close() when I use prepared statement in golang?

Comment: From the docs of [Prepare](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare): *"Prepare creates a prepared statement for later queries or executions. Multiple queries or executions may be run concurrently from the returned statement. The caller must call the statement's Close method when the statement **is no longer needed**."* That means, if you still need the stmt don't close it.

Comment: Whether you use defer or not depends on your use case, and whether a deferred statement is useful in that context.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`defer`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) is not a *requirement*, it's a *convenience* and it offers *safety*. What matters is that if you create / prepare a statement (which uses some resources internally and may also use resources in the database server itself), then sometime, some point in the future you do call its `Close()` method in order to release resources allocated by it.

Deferred functions are executed even if your function ends abruptly (e.g. you have an early `return` statement or even if your function panics), so using `defer` to close resources gives you safety that your code will not leak resources and / or memory.

Note that `defer` will only run when the surrounding function returns. There may be cases when it is possible or even appropriate to close the statement earlier, and not wait until the surrounding function returns. A good example could be if you have a `for` loop doing many-many iterations, you would not want all the statements created in each iterations to keep resources until the `for` loop completes. In this case it is recommended to close resources before the next iteration begins. And in this case you would simply write a `stmt.Close()` instead of `defer stmt.Close()`, because the latter would not close the statement immediately, only when the function returns.

Also note that "outsourcing" the loop's body to a separate function will also give you the possibility to use `defer` in that separate function, where the deferred close will happen before the next iteration begins. A variant of this may be that you use an anonymous function (a function literal) in the loop's body, where you also have the chance to use `defer`, e.g.:

```
for _, v := range values {
    func() {
        stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES(?)")
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
            return
        }
        defer stmt.Close()

        // Use stmt...
    }()
}
```